# Can I use a Planeswalker's ability when I took over its control this turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1. My opponent controls a Planeswalker and uses its ability. End of turn.
2. I play [In Bolas's Clutches](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442942) and target that Planeswalker. It comes under my control (right?).
3. Can I now use this Planeswalker's ability or do I have to wait another "round" because its ability was already used this  "round" by my opponent? (by "round" I mean two turns)

> #### In Bolas's Clutches
>
> **Types**: Legendary Enchantment — Aura Card
>   **Text**: Enchant permanent / You control enchanted permanent. / Enchanted permanent is legendary.

Comment: There's no such thing as a round in MTG

Comment: There are no rounds in the sense of "turns", though there are rounds in the CompRules: "draft rounds" (905.1a+b) and "mulligan rounds"(103.4b)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You may use one of the planeswalker's abilities during your turn.**

[In Bolas's Clutches](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIn%5d%2b%5bBolas%27s%5d%2b%5bClutches%5d) does indeed allow you to control planeswalkers, and each player's turn counts separately. If your opponent ended their turn, your turn is separate from that, those two turns do not count as the same turn.

> 606.3. A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.

Please note that the game structure doesn't have a concept of "rounds". In order of decreasing scope, the structure of MtG is as follows:

- Tournament (a series of matches)
- Match (series of games)
- Game (series of turns)
- Turn (series of phases)
- Phase (series of steps)
- Step (some phases don't have steps)

Comment: @corsiKa There is, in fact, at least one way to do so: [Teferi, Temporal Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389712)'s -10 ability is 'You get an emblem with "You may activate loyalty abilities of planeswalkers you control on any player's turn any time you could cast an instant."'